# Generate a table from period of time and each entry spans one hour

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, date-arithmetic, generate-series

For example I have 8am to 8pm.
I want the table where it can generate the table where it has entry one by one `starttime` and `endtime` (two columns):

```
8:00-9:00
9:00-10:00
....
19:00-20:00
```

Like this way. No date before the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) function to do that:

```
psql# select generate_series('2014-01-01 16:00'::timestamp, '2014-01-01 20:00'::timestamp, '1 hour');
   generate_series   
---------------------
 2014-01-01 16:00:00
 2014-01-01 17:00:00
 2014-01-01 18:00:00
 2014-01-01 19:00:00
 2014-01-01 20:00:00
(5 rows)
```

And then you can use:

```
SELECT
    t AS starttime,
    t + INTERVAL '1 hour' as endtime
FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES(
        '2014-01-01 16:00'::TIMESTAMP,
        '2014-01-01 20:00'::TIMESTAMP,
        '1 hour'
    ) AS t
```

To get the start and end times.

Alternatively, to just get the times, you can use:

```
SELECT
    '08:00'::time + (t || ' hours')::interval as starttime,
    '08:00'::time + ((t + 1)::text || ' hours')::interval as endtime
FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES(0, 12) AS t
```

Comment: I don't want the date info. just from 16:00-17:00 like this way

Answer (score 0):

Simpler, use a full timestamp with a dummy date component and cast to `time`:

```
SELECT t::time  AS starttime
     , t::time + interval '1h' AS endtime
FROM   generate_series('2000-1-1 08:00'::timestamp
                     , '2000-1-1 19:00'::timestamp
                     , interval '1h') t;
```

The same for `text` columns:

```
SELECT to_char(t, 'HH24:MI') AS starttime
     , to_char(t + interval '1h', 'HH24:MI') AS endtime
FROM   generate_series('2000-1-1 08:00'::timestamp
                     , '2000-1-1 19:00'::timestamp
                     , interval '1h') t;
```